# FluentNHibernate: HasMany mapping to methods (their backing fields)? / Foreign key not saved

Tags: foreign-keys, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to map to methods instead of properties?

I have a Customer class with a method "GetOrders()" typeof "ReadOnlyCollection" with backing field "_orders" typeof "IList".

I tried in CustomerMap:

```
HasMany<Order>(Reveal.Member<Customer>("_orders"))
    .KeyColumn("CustomerId").Cascade.All().Inverse().Not.LazyLoad();
```

But I get an exception when running the insert for a customer containing 1 order.

```
 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerId', table 'Order'; 
 column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Does mapping methods (or at least their backing fields) not work?
Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not map the Customer to the Orders also.